# C# When using a KeyPress event on a text box, why cant i enter a minus sign?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Im using VS2010, and I have a text box... I assign a KeyPress on the box, abd set the method like so:

```
private void MyButton_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I noticed that i am no longer able to enter any special keys such as the minus (-) and plus (+) sign into the textbox. Can someone please explain to me why i am no longer able to do this, and what i can do to fix this?

Ultimately I'm trying to only allow numeric keys to be entered, and i also want to allow the (-) minus sign, but if i cant get the minus sign in there, then i guess i wont be able to limit the text of the box

Comment: Turning Num LOCK On/Off didnt have any effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should finish the job for you.

```
private void MyButton_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9') return;
    if (e.KeyChar == '+' || e.KeyChar == '-') return;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Here is how it works. If the character typed is one that you want, simply return from the function and let the normal handler take care of it. All other characters are marked as handled and so processing on them stops. Since nothing is done with them they are essentially thrown away. You could put everything in one if statement but I left it this way for clarity

Comment: @downvoter why the down vote? you should at least explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a little and added logic that only accepts 1, 2 or +, which was one of your problem characters. Hope this helps you!

```
 private void MyButton_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (e.KeyChar == '1' || e.KeyChar == '2' || e.KeyChar == '+') textBox1.AppendText(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: simply appending the character might be right most of the time, but what if the users moves the cursor back to the middle of the number and tries to insert a character there?

Comment: Oh, good point! I like your code better. Thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should do like so:

```
    private void MyButton_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '1' || e.KeyChar == '2' || e.KeyChar == '+')
             e.Handled = false;
        else
             e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Of course, you'll want to replace the individual tests by a method that will return whether or not the key is allowed.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As it is now, your code won't allow anything to be entered. The e.Handled statement cancels the key stroke. The code below will allow any numeric character, and the minus sign. If you only want the minus sign in the first position in the textbox you will have to test the TextLength property before allowing the character.

```
private void MyButton_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e
{
    int i = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out i))
    {
        if (e.KeyChar.CompareTo('-')!=0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```